# Making my do while loop neater by removing repeating code

Tags: c++, do-while

Hi here is my question.

Write a program that uses a do-while statement. It reads in an integer
n from the keyboard. If n is not in the range 1 to 10 it makes an audible
“beep” and asks for another integer. If n is in the correct range, it writes
out “You have input n” and then exits.

Here is my answer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int number = 0;
    do
    {
      cout << "Enter an integer." << endl;
      cin >> number;
      if (!(number >= 1 && number <= 10))
      {
        Beep(400, 400);
      }
    }
    while (!(number >= 1 && number <= 10));
    cout << "You have input " << number << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

You can see the line

```
(!(number >= 1 && number <= 10))
```

is repeated. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: There's a way of beeping that's a bit more standard C++-oriented: `'\a'`.

Comment: 1. Use a function. 2. perform the check once and save it to a variable.  3. Your loop ends even if the user inputs an invalid number (one that "beeps"). On a side note, your condition is weird.  How about `if(number < 1 || number > 10)`?

Comment: @EdS., Someone's been practising taking DeMorgan's Laws and applying them to comparison operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int number = 0;
    bool invalid_input = true;
    do
    {
      cout << "Enter an integer." << endl;
      cin >> number;
      invalid_input = !(number >= 1 && number <= 10); 
      if (invalid_input)
      {
        Beep(400, 400);
      }
    }
    while (invalid_input);
    cout << "You have input " << number << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int GetNumber()
{
    int number;
    cout << "Enter an integer." << endl;
    cin >> number;
    return number;
}

void main()
{
    int n = GetNumber();

    while(n < 1 || n > 10)
    {
        Beep(400, 400);
        n = GetNumber();
    }

    cout << "You have input " << n << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: This is called feature abuse.

Comment: @EdS. So make it a function instead of a lambda. Makes no difference.

Comment: It makes a difference in the clarity of the code.  You have slightly obfuscated what used to be a completely straightforward loop.

Comment: @EdS. There, I made it old old style. Just for you.

Comment: It wasn't the lambda so much I guess, more the structure of the loop... anyway, +1

Comment: Was it a do-while loop before?

Comment: It was a for loop that used a lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps...

```
int number = 0;
while (true)
{
  cout << "Enter an integer." << endl;
  if (cin >> number && number >= 1 && number <= 10)
      break;
  Beep(400, 400);
}
cout << "You have input " << number << endl;
system("PAUSE");
```

Comment: This is the version I'd prefer; it avoids code duplication and doesn't perform redundant checks.

Comment: @jamesdlin I was somewhat of the same mind when I wrote it. Even the accepted answer does little more than move the condition check to a boolean flag, which is promptly checked twice anyway. The optimized asm (laughing as I write that; its a UI prompt for heaven sake) would probably show it ultimately as this when finished. It was also the only answer that checked the stream input validity.